# How to return Nothing?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a `Widget build(BuildContext context)` which returns some `Container` with elements inside, but when 'else' comes in the end in some cases i dont want to return an empty Container because it still takes some space. how can i remove these spaces?

[image]

Comment: empty Containers do not take any space. What you see must be whatever you put the empty Container in

Comment: Why do you need to return something?  If this is in the children: list of some multiwidget layout thing, just use collection literal "if" syntax to remove the element if not needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Container` imposes zero constraints on its children and tells no information about its size to its parent.

If you're confused by this statement, before continuing reading, read [this Flutter's documentation page](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints) about layouting.

This being said, I would do the following:

1. I'd write `SizedBox.shrink()` instead of `Container()` inside your `else` clause. This widget tells its parent that he wants to be of size "zero" (as you've requested). **NOTE.** This is just for readability purposes. A parent can *still* force a minimum height or width onto its children;
2. I'd check the constraints and / or the layouting your parent widget forces onto children. For example, if it's a `Column`, then I'd set its `mainAxisAlignment` to `MainAxisAlignment.start` so that now no space is supposed to be inserted between its children. There are way more possible cases though (probably infinite), so further investigation should be done.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

even though the previous answer is totally fine and true.
but the flutter engine will configure and paint any widget on the screen even if it's empty, using `SizedBox` will still need to be painted and assigned to the widget tree even if it's empty. so it's not the performant way to do it

I asked the same thing a time, I searched then I found this:

https://pub.dev/packages/nil

A package that provides a low expensive widget that just take place but it's nothing in widget tree paint.

Comment: I'm curious about this: how can a render object affect performance that much? Isn't layouting and rendering the bread and butter of Flutter, with its very fast layouting algorithm?

Comment: still nothing changed with nil

Comment: you can see the source code of it, it will make sense after you read it